# What is the best place to have config entries in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

My PhoneGap app uses the Web API to get/update add data. So in the controller code, I have references to the API's like 'api/services/User/' etc. But while making the call I need to give reference to the host where these services are hosted. So I would like to know what is the best way to accomplish this?

Can I store this information in the Config.xml file available? If yes, then how to read the entries from config file, since it is entirely JavaScript. But if there is any other better way of doing this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I usually have several values like that, and usually put a js file that has these parameters set like this:

```js
 var MyConfig = {
    mode: 'debug',
    //mode: 'qa',
    //mode 'prod',
    AjaxHost: function(arg) {
        switch (this.mode) {
            case 'prod':
                return 'http://svc.mydomain.com/' + arg;
                break;
            case 'qa':
                return 'http://qa.mydomain.com/' + arg;
                break;
            default:
                return 'http://dev.mydomain.com/' + arg;
                break;
        };
    }   
};
```

Then I can use it where needed:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: MyConfig.AjaxHost('api/webservice')
    ...
})...
```

Then I just need to remember to uncomment the correct "mode" line when building the app.